# Write out a simplified SOP expression for a function

Tags: logic

$0 \space 1 \space 2\space  3\space  4\space  5\space  6\space  7 \\
15\space  14\space  13\space  12\space  11\space  10\space  9\space  8\space  \\
16\space  17\space  18\space  19\space  20\space  21\space  22\space  23\space  \\ 
31\space  30\space  29\space  28\space  27\space  26\space  25\space  24\space  \\ 
32\space  33\space  34\space  35\space  36\space  37\space  38\space  39\space  \\
47\space  46\space  45\space  44\space  43\space  42\space  41\space  40\space  \\
48\space  49\space  50\space  51\space  52\space  53\space  54\space  55\space  \\
63\space  62\space  61\space  60\space  59\space  58\space  57\space  56\space $

Assume that the binary numbers $A_5A_4A_3A_2A_1A_0$ and $B_5B_4B_3B_2B_1B_0$ represent two labels on the matrix(a chess board) above. Define a function F that returns 1 if a Bishop(in a chess game) at the first label is able to move to the second label in two or fewer moves, otherwise returns 0. Write out the simplified Sum of Products expression for F in terms of $S_k$ whereby $S_k$ is defined as the difference between $A_k$ and $B_k$.

I have no idea how to solve this. Help appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

> A bishop on any square can move to any other square of the same color in at most 2 moves.  So you just need to determine if the two squares are the same color.

Further hint:

> Group the numbers into two groups, "black numbers" and "white numbers", according to a checkerboard pattern.  Do you notice anything about which numbers are in each group?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Observe that a bishop can reach any square whose parity matches that of it starting point within two moves. Now think about how this parity might be related to $S_0$.